# Azure release pipeline cannot find artifact in path

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a build and release path to build some jar files and deploy them to my azure cloud subscription/resource group. I have been wrking on this for a while, it keeps failing and is desperating.

This is my build pipeline, for specifically the publish artifact task (I understand I must use PublishPipelineArtifact and not PublishBuildArtifact as it is the current preferred option, although build should work too as long as I mark my jars)

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/
    artifactName: 'drop'
    artifactType: 'pipeline'
```

I see in my PublishArtifact logs that my files are being read from: /home/vsts/work/1/s
Unfortunatelly no info to where is being copied appears

[image]

If I click on the artifacts created I can see they are moved under

https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_build/results?buildId=XXXXX&view=artifacts&pathAsName=false&type=publishedArtifacts

More concretely under drop/s in what I understand is the stagering directory

So far so good. I have my project built on drop and I can see my jars.

Then when going to the release pipeline to deploy to the cloud

[image]

The tasks are run and this is my copy task to copy from build to release

[image]

But at the end it fails because after downloading apparently without problems the artifact it says it cannot find it, when even in the task manager from the release pipeline UI I can select manually the jar file as seen in the picture 2.

Seems to be a problem copying to the release branch, or that being properly copied it cannot read it

[image]

Seems to be a missmatch between path system variables, or even the slashes as I'm copying a jar from a linux build pipeline to a what is seems to be a Windows NFTS path. This is awful. I have been stuck for a while and I have tried all it came to mind. Can someone give me an idea on why the artifact seems to be downloading well but then it sad it cannot find the jar file? Feel free to correct any other misconception you think that exists in my post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide the YAML you are using for this?

Comment: The yaml part that is interesting is in the seconf paragraph. The SO parser gave it a strange format. I'll change it now. Nevertheless I discovered the issue to my problem. Apparently I cannot select jar files, just wars or zips. Nuts I say. I'll post the solution in a while